# Cakephp button text formatting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

This should be easy.
I have a button in my view:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link("Edit", array('controller'=>'Competitors','action'=>'edit', $competitor['competitors']['id']) ); ?>
```

The button adds a link to edit the populated user.
Now, I want to add a button instead of the "Edit" text only, so I added:

```
<?php  echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array('controller'=>'Competitors','action'=>'edit', $competitor['competitors']['id']), array('class' => 'btn btn-info btn-xs', 'target' => '_self'))?>
```

that is fine, but I want to add a "glyphicon" icon in front of the text "Edit" but still inside the button, like this:

!http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/images/glyphicon_demo.jpg

so I tried:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(
         $this->Html->tag('span', 'Edit', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit')),
        array('controller'=>'Competitors','action'=>'edit', $competitor['competitors']['id']), array('class' => 'btn btn-info btn-xs', 'target' => '_self'))?>
```

But is not working, how can I just add the glyphicon icon and keep the formatting of the text.
Please guys, I need help.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape the link title!

Add this option to the options of the link method:

```
'escape' => false
```

So the code will be:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(
         $this->Html->tag('span', 'Edit', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit')),
        array('controller'=>'Competitors','action'=>'edit', $competitor['competitors']['id']), array('class' => 'btn btn-info btn-xs', 'target' => '_self','escape' => false))?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it didn't quite worked, but, with your answer and the other guy that responded I was able to do it. Here is the code for your reference:
`<?php echo $this->Html->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit', array('controller'=>'Competitors','action'=>'edit', $competitor['competitors']['id']), array('escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-xs', 'target' => '_self'));?>`

Answer (score 1):

To use html elements in your CakePHP Html link you need to set 'escape'=> false as the third argument.

For example:

```
echo $this->Html->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit', array('action' => 'edit'), array('escape' => false));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it didn't quite worked, but, with your answer and the other guy that responded I was able to do it. Here is the code for your reference:
`<?php echo $this->Html->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit', array('controller'=>'Competitors','action'=>'edit', $competitor['competitors']['id']), array('escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-xs', 'target' => '_self'));?>`

Comment: Right, I provided an example only.  It is expected to be tweaked to fit your needs, but the jest of it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help. Using a combinations of your answers I got the solution, here it is:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit', array('controller'=>'Competitors','action'=>'edit', $competitor['competitors']['id']), array('escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-xs', 'target' => '_self'));?>
```